# qty_available for a product from specific picking/delivery

Tags: odoo

Is there a way to get the qty_available of a specific delivery/stock picking (I always get one product per delivery)?

I have the `stock.picking` of the delivery.

Something in line with the following but can't figure out which context variable to provide for the picking

```
self.product_id.with_context({'picking_id' : self .picking_id, 'strict' : True}).qty_available
```

Thank you!

Tried, on pure guessing as I could not find any lead in the code of the product model

```
self.product_id.with_context({'picking_id' : self .picking_id, 'strict' : True}).qty_available
```